# Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) not working for my case

Tags: iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify the element in IE using below xpath values in selenium webdriver but it is not working for any of them

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userName']"))
```

Also tried complete xpath but did not work -

```
//frameset[contains(@id,'topFrameset')]/frame[4]/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/form/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input
```

following is the input tag on the page which I am trying to access (there are no duplicate id, or name or class on the page)

```
<input name="userName" class="LoginTextField" id="userName" 
    onkeyup="OnKeyDownOnObject()" type="text" valign="middle"/>
```

Note that this input tag is inside iframe as per below entire path

```
//frameset/frame[4]/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/form/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input
```

Please let me know if there is standard way in webdriver to capture elements in iframe.

Comment: Since, the input tag is inside a frame, you would've to switch to it first, before trying to access the **input** tag. Can you please tell me what is the iframe's id or name, in which you are trying to locate the input element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, your **concerned frame is the 4th one under the frameset tag**, you can **first switch to it and then try locating the element**.

Please see if the below code works out for you:

```
//To switch to the required frame, if found, in 20 seconds
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frameset[contains(@id,'topFrameset')]/frame[4]")));
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while switching to the frame. "+e.getMessage());
}

//locating the input element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked by switching to iframe first then accessing using input tag.